# How to Search for file and path in Linux

Tags: linux

How can i search files and print out their directory.
I have been trying
`ls -R | grep "filename.txt"`
however it only prints out the filename. How can i modify this command to printout the path of the file  or is their any command
Thankyou

Comment: Take a look at the [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command.

Comment: find . -name filename.txt

Comment: Besides `find`, the `realpath` command gives you the full file path to a file. `realpath filename.txt` could return `/path/to/file/filename.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the "find" command in the terminal.

Ex: `find -name filename.txt`

You can define a directory to start the search:

Ex: `find /path/to/start -name filename.txt`

You can also find match a pattern:

Ex: `find -name "*.txt"`

Using a / will search the entire file system, but this can cause a heavy load on your computer:

Ex: `find / -name filename.txt`

Comment: You need to quote the pattern : `find -name "*.txt"`